# Using column names as arguments in existing functions in dplyr mutate()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=LETTERS[1:3], Text=c("A/B", "C/D","B/C"))

  ID Text
1  A  A/B
2  B  C/D
3  C  B/C
```

I want to check, for each row, if the value in `ID` is present in `Text`:

```
# desired output
  ID Text Present
1  A  A/B TRUE
2  B  C/D FALSE
3  C  B/C TRUE
```

Using the column names in conjunction with mutate() and grepl() does not work (third row is incorrect):

```
df %>% mutate(Present=grepl(pattern=ID, Text))
  ID Text Present
1  A  A/B  TRUE
2  B  C/D FALSE
3  C  B/C FALSE

Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `Match`.
ℹ `Match = grepl(pattern = ID, Text)`.
ℹ argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I know dplyr has some requirements with how to specify variables as arguments, but I can only find examples of people running into an issue writing their *own* functions, whereas I want to use an *existing* function. I've tried those techniques anyways:

```
df %>% mutate(Present=grepl(pattern={{ ID }}, Text))
Error in (function (arg)  : object 'ID' not found

df %>% mutate(Present=grepl(pattern=.data$ID, Text))
  ID Text Present
1  A  A/B    TRUE
2  B  C/D   FALSE
3  C  B/C   FALSE
Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `Present`.
ℹ `Present = grepl(pattern = .data$ID, Text)`.
ℹ argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 
# same issue as previous code block

df %>% mutate(Present=grepl(pattern=enquo(ID), Text))
  ID Text Present
1  A  A/B   FALSE
2  B  C/D   FALSE
3  C  B/C   FALSE
Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `Present`.
ℹ `Present = grepl(pattern = enquo(ID), Text)`.
ℹ argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 

df %>% mutate(Present=grepl(pattern= .data[[ID]], Text))
Error in splice(dot_call(capture_dots, frame_env = frame_env, named = named,  : 
  object 'ID' not found

df %>% mutate(Present=grepl(pattern=!!ID, Text))
Error in splice(dot_call(capture_dots, frame_env = frame_env, named = named,  : 
  object 'ID' not found

df %>% mutate(Present=grepl(pattern=!!enquo(ID), Text))
Error in (function (arg)  : object 'ID' not found

df %>% mutate(Present=grepl(pattern=enquo(!!ID), Text))
Error in splice(dot_call(capture_dots, frame_env = frame_env, named = named,  : 
  object 'ID' not found
```

I'm at a loss. This feels like it should be a really simple thing to do.

Comment: `df %>% mutate(Present = stringr::str_detect(Text, ID))`

Comment: Alternatively: `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Present = grepl(ID, Text))` -- this is necessary because `grepl` works with a single pattern (see the note "argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"), so if the pattern varies by row you need to calculate each row separately, doable with `rowwise`, equivalent to grouping every row into its own group.   The `stringr::str_detect` approach works without it because it is vectorized over both string and pattern, not just string.

Comment: Thanks for these alternatives. I guess I don't understand why grepl() is considering ID to be longer than 1 if mutate() should be acting on each row individually

Comment: Many (most?) R functions are vectorized, meaning they are designed to be applied to all the elements of a vector at once, rather than line by line.  Good explanation: https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/   In the case of `grepl`, the `text` term is vectorized but the pattern is not. That's how it was designed but we could adapt it like here: https://biolitika.si/vectorizing-functions-in-r-is-easy.html

Comment: Interesting, I always thought mutate() somehow overrode the vectorization and made it specific to the rows. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str_detect` solution in the comments is good. You could also use `purrr::map2_lgl` to make the `grepl` act across rows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Present = map2_lgl(ID, Text, grepl))

  ID Text Present
1  A  A/B    TRUE
2  B  C/D   FALSE
3  C  B/C    TRUE
```